# How can I set up a guest account on a TP-Link TL-WR1043ND?

Tags: wireless-router

How can I set up a guest account on a TP-Link TL-WR1043ND wireless router?

Comment: Guest account for what?  What should/shouldn't the guest be able to do?  Have you checked the [manual](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-WR1043ND#down) to see if it has your answer?  Please edit your original question with the answers to these questions.

Comment: No-restriction guest account will help me not to share the primary password with the visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this review](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-reviews/31653-tp-link-tl-wr1043nd-ultimate-wireless-n-gigabit-router-reviewed?start=1), your router doesn't offer a separate guest network option.